# All map tasks reached 100%, and stuck

Tags: exception, hadoop, flush

I use Hadoop 1.2.1, and applying Scala to write Hadoop applications. The Scala wordcount example works very well in my machine. Then I tested my program and met a problem.

The map achieved to 100% and got stuck, and no reduce tasks are launched. After checking JobTracker webpage, I found that it was still in the mapping phase, even though it has been in state of 100%. Then I checked logs in tmp folder. I noticed that a exception in syslog in attemp_...

The logs has following information:

```
2014-04-20 21:53:15,297 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: Starting flush of map output
2014-04-20 22:03:20,989 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task: Communication exception: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: JvmValidate Failed. Ignoring request from task: attempt_201404202149_0003_m_000000_0, with JvmId: jvm_201404202149_0003_m_1601373058

    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.validateJVM(TaskTracker.java:3465)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.ping(TaskTracker.java:3598)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:587)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1432)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1428)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1426)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1113)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.ping(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$TaskReporter.run(Task.java:685)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

I was searching org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException. But no useful information is found. Does anyone know what's wrong here?

Comment: Can you try the same program using Java and then compare the results just to eliminate if it has something to do with Scala implementation

Comment: I rewrote my hadoop implementation using java, and it works now. I think there might be something wrong in scala.